How can jitter be higher than the clock period?
I'm trying to figure out if I could use an oscillator IC for this AR0134CS image sensor or if I need a crystal oscillator circuit, keeping in mind the signal will go through a PLL in a microcontroller first.
Looking at the datasheet it lists the period as being between 20ns and 166ns, and yet the maximum jitter is a whopping 600ns. I thought jitter here means the maximum allowed deviation of each clock edge from its ideal timing, but clearly if that were the case the edges could be so far off, the signal would be unrecognisable as a clock at all. So what does it actually mean?


Hmm, is there a typo in the datasheet such that the units for tJITTER should be picoseconds rather than nanoseconds?

or it might be that the chip is just very tolerant of jittery clocks, because it runs its own clock cleanup? If the input clock is for data, data clocks don't need to be regular - take, for example, SPI, where a clock cycle's (and thus a bit's) length doesn't have any defined relationship to previous or later clock cycles.

The clock is used for a PLL in this chip, can a PLL run with such high jitter? I would have thought no.

There are many definitions of jitter...
Cycle-to-cycle jitter is the maximum difference between any two adjacent clock periods.
Period jitter is the maximum deviation of any clock period from its mean clock period. This implies the "mean clock period" is measured over a certain number of periods, or its time equivalent.
Absolute jitter is the difference between the position of a clock's edge and where it should "ideally" be. Quotes around "ideally" because that really means where the edge should be considering the average frequency of the oscillator, which again implies the average is taken over some period of time.
Suppose a clock oscillator having frequency wander of 0.6ppm, which is pretty low. That means over one second, sometimes the number of cycles in that second will be the exact frequency, sometimes it will be 0.6ppm higher, sometimes 0.6ppm lower. The clock is still usable as a clock, but it looks a bit like an accordion. Over one second, an error of 0.6ppm is 600ns, so this oscillator has 600ns absolute jitter. To get the same absolute jitter over a shorter time interval requires proportionally higher frequency wander.
I think this is about ensuring the PLL in the image sensor locks. However, a PLL implies a filter, which means there is a lowpass cutoff frequency in the PLL filter. This filter operates on the VCO's control, so it is not filtering the clock itself, but the frequency components of its jitter. Below the cutoff, it will simply follow the input clock and replicate its jitter into the output, which means slow frequency drift and absolute jitter in the input clock won't prevent lock. Above this jitter cutoff frequency the filter will work to clean it up, trying to average the input frequency. Too much jitter above the PLL lowpass cutoff frequency  can cause the phase frequency detector to lose track and the PLL to lose lock.
But that cutoff frequency doesn't seem to be specified, so it's hard to know over which period of time the specified absolute jitter should be measured...
That's a bit of an issue, because pretty much any oscillator will have more than 600ns absolute jitter if you measure it for long enough (seconds, minutes) but the PLL filter cutoff is probably in the tens of kHz (as usual), so the time interval over which the absolute jitter should be measured is probably in the tens of µs. In that case it should work fine with any reasonably clean clock.

It's feasible that the input clock jitter specification is based on the absolute jitter time difference between the position of a clock edge and where ideally it should be if the clock frequency was held constant. This can be due to a low-frequency clock-frequency movement over several thousands of clock cycles.
Providing that the clock eventually returns to where it ideally should be, you could envisage a particularly large time discrepancy before it settles down. Small example: -


The datasheet Table 17. RISE AND FALL TIMES gives Clock Period Jitter (RMS) as 50 ps max and Clock Cycle to Cycle Jitter (RMS) as 100 ps max which are the other metrics in the linked reference. So agree that the tJITTER with a max of 600 ns is likely to be the absolute jitter metric.

Table 17 seems to be about the HiSPi interface, to be clear I am using the parallel interface so I don't think it's relevant.

@Blue On looking again looks like I misunderstood Table 17, which as you point out is about the HiSPi interface which uses the SLVSC_N / SLVSC_P differential output clock, rather than about the EXTCLK single ended input clock.

@Andy aka, If it's true that this is about absolute jitter, then I'm not sure how I would determine if I can use a particular oscillator for EXTCLK on this chip. Is it possible that a datasheet would leave something important like that completely ambiguous? Whether the PLL will work depends mostly on the period jitter does it not?

@Blue that might happen so choose an oscillator from a reliable supplier and double check the wording in the data sheet. Anything xtal based would be very stable but, anything based around "an oscillator" and PLL will be worse but, 600 ns is an awfully decent tolerance on absolute jitter so, most will fit the bill. However, there are some oscillators from ADI/LinearTech that probably would be borderline due to their internal architecture. Bottom line is that the simpler the oscillator, the less likely it will be to cause problems.

In order to have a phase detector, it must be within 1 cycle so if the minimum input clock is 166 ns and the jitter tolerance must be a fraction of 1 cycle, then what is the real mixer f?.
This means the PLL is a fractional-N PLL to mix at a lower frequency like 250 kHz, so it must divide the input by some integer in order to mix in order to have fractional MHz pixel clocks with more resolution like 74.25 MHz. Then the output f can be M/N x fin.
If my answer is correct then 600 ns / 4us and the jitter tolerance is 25% is consistent with my assumptions then you do not have to think of different jitter definitions.
"All the internal clocks can run from a single master input clock running between 6 and 50 MHz.
The maximum output pixel rate is 74.25 Mp/s,
corresponding to a clock rate of 74.25 MHz"
From the datasheet.
